# Copy CView contents to a bitmap

Tags: mfc, bitmap, cview

I'd like to create a bitmap copy of the current contents of my CView, which may or may not be currently visible on the screen.  Here is the code I've added to my OnDraw function:

```
void 
MyView::OnDraw
( 
    CDC* pDC 
)
{

    ... normal processing ... 

    // Copy the view contents to a bitmap.

    CDC dc;
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC( pDC );

    if ( m_pBitmap != NULL )
    {
        delete m_pBitmap;
    }

    m_pBitmap = new CBitmap();
    m_pBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap( &dc, szView.cx, szView.cy );

    CBitmap* pOld = ( CBitmap* )dc.SelectObject( m_pBitmap );
    dc.BitBlt( 0, 0, szView.cx, szView.cy, pDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );
    dc.SelectObject( pOld );

}
```

But now when I examine the bitmap I can see that there is only 1 bit per pixel.  I'm sure I'm missing something, can anyone help?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that &dc needed to be changed to pDC in the call to CreateCompatibleBitmap.

Kevin